# What would be the easiest explanation to understand toLocaleString and how to set it up in html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
//Total Amount Sum Calculator
var sum = 0;

function f(val) {
  sum += val;
  document.getElementById("d-total").value = sum;
}

function reset() {
  sum = 0;
  document.getElementById("d-total").value = sum;
}

//Automatic Comma
function FormatCurrency(ctrl) {
  //Check if arrow keys are pressed - we want to allow navigation around textbox using arrow keys
  if (event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 40) {
    return;
  }

  var val = ctrl.value;

  val = val.replace(/,/g, "")
  ctrl.value = "";
  val += '';
  x = val.split('.');
  x1 = x[0];
  x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';

  var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

  while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  }

  ctrl.value = x1 + x2;
}
//Restrict Characters (Numbers Only)
function CheckNumeric() {
  return event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57 || event.keyCode == 46;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="input-char-amo" id="d-total" value="10000" step="10000" min="10000" max="5000000" onkeypress="return CheckNumeric()" / required>

<button type="reset" class="correction" onclick="reset()">reset</button><br>
<div class="amount-buttons-a">
  <button type="button" id="1" onclick="f(10000)" class="btn-amount">10000</button>
  <button type="button" id="2" onclick="f(20000)" class="btn-amount">20000</button>
  <button type="button" id="3" onclick="f(50000)" class="btn-amount">50000</button>
</div>
<div class="amount-buttons-b">
  <button type="button" id="4" onclick="f(100000)" class="btn-amount">100000</button>
  <button type="button" id="5" onclick="f(500000)" class="btn-amount">500000</button>
  <button type="button" id="6" onclick="f(1000000)" class="btn-amount">1000000</button>
</div>
```

I'm trying to set my input field to automatically add comma when customer click a button with specified amount. Someone mentioned toLocaleString but the documentation linked was quite hard to understand and doesn't show how to link in html. What would be the easiest explanation for it? Or does anyone have other way to add comma automatically when customer clicked a button with specified amount?

Here is what I had done. It still doesn't automatically add a comma.

Comment: Have you tried the doc on MDN ? It is pretty clear and has examples. Here is the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: Already edited. Thanks! @Andreas

Comment: So the desired output is something like `10000,20000,50000` ?

Comment: No. It should be 10,000 20,000 50,000 @BilalAhmed